# View PDF from Php using AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pdf

I have an application that needs to display the pdf from MySQL database based on the pmid based on an AJAX call.
The code for loading pdf from MySQL works perfectly fine. The issue I face is using an AJAX call to view the PDF based on the pmid.
Here is my php code in `readpdf/pdf.php`

```
<?php
include ('../model/connection1.php');

$pmid = $_POST['pmid'];
$file= $pmid.'.pdf';
$dbh = Db::getInstance();
$sql = "SELECT pdf_content FROM pdf_binary_content WHERE pmid ='".$pmid."'";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(); 
$content = $stmt->fetchAll();
$pdfcontent= $content['0']['pdf_content'];
echo $pdfcontent;
?>
<!--<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($pdfcontent) ?>" type="application/pdf" style="height:800px;width:60%"></object> -->
```

The code in my .js file is

```
function checkPaperExist(pmid, kind) {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../readpdf/pdf.php',
        data: {
            pmid: pmid
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#pdfview').show();           
            $("object").attr('data',data).hide().show();
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("parse show table error");
        }
    });
```

I get the correct output in  `console.log(data)`, I need help with using the `object tag` in the success function.

Thanks in Advance

-----EDIT-----
The PDF should show under the following div

```
<div id="drop" class="container-fluid"> 
     <div id="rightDiv" class="container-fluid main inline-div col-md-9" >
        <div id="pdfview" >
          <object data="data:application/pdf;base64" type="application/pdf" style="height:800px;width:60%"></object> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you could do `$("object").attr('data',data).hide().show();`

Comment: It didnt work. I also added an edit

Comment: instead of passing just the `$pdfcontent` from your PHP script, try passing `echo "data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($pdfcontent) ?>";`